# refer all the actions added to the view

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have created  some actions to the view toolbar by using Action not commands.
Now how do I get the all the actions available to that view toolbar?

Example. Created a view and added three actions called A,B,C now should return
all three actions to this view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to find the actions in your view part code. You can get the view tool bar manager using:

```java
IToolBarManager toolBarMgr = getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager();
```

you can then find the contribution item for your action using:

```java
IContributionItem actionItem = toolBarMgr.find("action id");
```

The item should be an instance of `ActionContributionItem` so you can use:

```java
IAction action = ((ActionContributionItem)actionItem).getAction();
```